# VSCode hangs when trying to run a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a Jupyter notebook in VSCode. I have successfully run notebooks in the past, but something has happened to make VSCode "hang" when I try running. When I hit run, the terminal shows the file location and the location of python.exe as expected (shown in the first image, with some personal information redacted), but nothing ever happens. The code never completes and the cells never output. I get a small "pending" icon of a clock and an arrow (shown in the second image) to tell me a cell is running, but even the most basic "Hello, world" never completes or gives an error. I have no trouble running regular python files, and if I export an ipynb to py I can run it, but I cannot run the ipynb itself. Trying to restart the Jupyter kernel also seems to hang, never completing and never crashing or erroring. The only clue I really have is that when I hit F5 to run, there's no python version showing in the bottom left corner, the way there is when I run py files (third image is while trying to run ipynb and fourth image is while successfully running py).

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Jupyter extension from VSCode and restarting VSCode between every step. I have tried swapping between python.exe and conda.exe in the terminal settings python.condapath. I have checked that the windows terminal is cmd. I've tried creating new notebooks in VSCode that only have print("Hello, world"). I have tried the command "Select interpreter to start Jupyter server" and selected the correct version of Python, but nothing has changed any time I've tried to run.

I am using Anaconda version 4.10.3, VSCode 1.61.2, IPython version 7.9.0, and Jupyter notebook version 6.4.3.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]